# COM "class is not registered" in case if using additional dll. How to debug this error?

Tags: com, activex, labview

The situation is that. I run Labview and from one via ActiveX pallet call my COM object method. And it works, I walk through my code with debugger.

But when I start to use (uncomment) code from side dll I see "class is not registered" error in Labview. My additional dll and its dependencies located in separate directory. So I tried to set PATH environment variable to this directory and after that run Labview. But is still doesn't work.

So the question is how to debug this situation? I looked through event logger but didn't found anything related.

P.S. I created my own synthetic application in C++ which calls the same method as Labview via COM too. And it works.

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  You'll see Labview reading the registry to locate the component.  With the expectation that it can't find the registry entry, that's what produces "Class is not registered".  Compare to the same trace you get from your test program.  Not registering the component correctly or trying to use a 32-bit component from a 64-bit process are the common causes.

Comment: Use Process Monitor to see where it's looking for dependencies. Properly registered COM components are internally loaded with `LoadLibraryEx()` function which has well-documented search order.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you for advice. I compared ProcMon logs and find out that Labview finds right dll, loads it, read it (in several offsets) and close it. After that occurs error about "unregistered class".

Comment: @sharptooth, you gave me an idea!  I added to first variant of code loading corresponding library. At first I tried LoadLibrary function on my dll and it returned  NULL. After that I tried to use LoadLibraryEx function. And it worked correctly with these flags: LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR.

The problem is still alive. The question is how to make COM find dependencies? (Seems that setting PATH is not working).

Comment: Process Monitor will show you what's going on know and you can then try to get somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in hard defined base dll address. Labview used this address and COM dlls couldn't use that space.

I suppose report is incorrect ("class is not registered") because class is registered, but corresponding dll couldn't be loaded.